# How os data loaded or synced in SnowFlake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are considering to use snowflake. I tried looking into the documentation and google, but without luck. How does snowflake query/store data? As an example if I have a CSV file, database, datalake ... is it like real time querying vs the sources, or does it replicate data to snowflake? If replication, how often does it update?

Comment: Hi - Snowflake is a database so you load data into it and then query it using SQL,  just like any other database. Can you clarify what you are asking - do you want to know how to load data into Snowflake, for example?

Comment: Basically you can load data into Snowflake from different sources (other databases, files, etc) and query it, but you can also query data stored on external sources like a datalake via [External Tables](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-external-intro.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe an introduction to the Snowflake Architecture is helping you here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/intro-key-concepts.html

Let's split up your query in two parts:

1. How does Snowflake store data? Basically Snowflake is storing data in it's own proprietary file format. The files are are called micro partitions, are in hybrid columnar format and are stored in for example S3 in case you are using Snowflake on AWS.
2. How does Snowflake query data? For this Snowflake is leveraging compute instances called Virtual Warehouses, which correspond to compute instances of your cloud provider underneath. With them, the files are accessed and queried.